# Plotting sawtooth with a duty cycle

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am familiar with the sawtooth function, but I need a sawtooth with a duty cycle where there is spaces between the peaks.

thankyou[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
sawtooth[x_, τ_, p_] = Max[0, Mod[τ - x, p, τ - p]/τ];
Plot[sawtooth[x, 1/2, 2], {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I apologize. I posted an image of what I mean. Im sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Can I get a fourier series for this? Im not geting a result when I use the Fourierseries function